# MYSQL Array Variable (No store prodecure, No temporarily table)

Tags: mysql

As mention in the title, I would like to know any solution for this by not using store prodecure, temporarily table etc.

Compare **Query#1** and **Query#3**, **Query#3** get worst performance result. Does it have any workaround to put in variable but without impact the performance result.

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
create table `order`(
    id BIGINT(20) not null auto_increment,
    transaction_no varchar(20) not null,
    primary key (`id`),
    unique key uk_transaction_no (`transaction_no`)
);

insert into `order` (`id`,`transaction_no`)
value (1,'10001'),(2,'10002'),(3,'10003'),(4,'10004');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
explain select * from `order` where transaction_no in ('10001','10004');
```

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | order |  | range | uk_transaction_no | uk_transaction_no | 22 |  | 2 | 100 | Using where; Using index |

---

**Query #2**

```
set @transactionNos = "10001,10004";
```

There are no results to be displayed.

---

**Query #3**

```
explain select * from `order` where find_in_set(transaction_no, @transactionNos);
```

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | order |  | index |  | uk_transaction_no | 22 |  | 4 | 100 | Using where; Using index |

---

Comment: What is the question? now it is absolutely unclear... PS. What is the reason for posting the link to clear fiddle? PPS. If you need in "array column" then you may use JSON datatype column which stores JSON array (and it can be even indexed - see "multivalued indexes" in RM).

Comment: Had remove the link, it's copy from fiddle. My question is on how to use variable to replace it without impact the performance. Let's I have multiple select query that using the same variable

Comment: You may use variable as-is. Or you may store it - in some service table, for example. Either static storing or dynamic specifying, I do not see any 3rd way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short Answer:**  See [*Sargeability*](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/28838/sargeable)

**Long Answer:**

MySQL makes no attempt to optimize an expression when an indexed column when it is hidden inside a function call such as `FIND_IN_SET()`, `DATE()`, etc.  Your Query 3 will always be performed as a full table scan or a full index scan.

So the only way to optimize what you are doing is to construct

```
IN ('10001','10004')
```

That is often difficult to achieve when "binding" a list of values.  `IN(?)` will not work in most APIs to MySQL.

Comment: The binding issue is unfortuante. I've taken to either generating multiple variables: `" IN (@1, @2, @3, @4)"` and binding them individually, or devolving to generating SQL statement (which is safe if not using `string` types)